# How to emulate PHP CURL with Python GAE?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, curl

I have the following PHP script, which acts as proxy to get video stream:

```
<?php
$c = curl_init();
$lp = array(
"username" => "yourlogin", 
"password" => "yourpassword"
);
$camId = "12345"; 
$cam_ = "1234567890123"; 

curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "/tmp/cookiejar.jar");
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($lp));
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, "https://login.example.com/eaidit/eaiditweb/outerlogin.do");
curl_exec($c);

curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "");
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, "https://login.example.com/eaidit/eaiditweb/redirect.do?redirectto=https://video.example.com/");
curl_exec($c);

curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "");
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, "https://video.example.com/camera/ajaxGetVideoUrl?id=".$camId."&_=".$cam_."");
$page = curl_exec($c);
$decoded = json_decode($page, true);

curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "");
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, $decoded["live"]["url"][0]);
curl_exec($c);
curl_close($c);
?>
```

I would like to do the same with python GAE. The main question I have - what this script sends as output and how can I do it with python GAE?

Comment: [URL Fetch PHP API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/urlfetch/)

Comment: @JaimeGómez, sorry, I haven't mentioned it initially - I would like to implement it with Python version of GAE. But anyway, GAE URL fetch (either PHP or Python) just return what has been received, should I just output the same?

Comment: [URL Fetch Python API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/)